# how to add overflow menu inside any layout using support library

Tags: android

I want to add overrflow menu inside layout not in toolbar,i am using android support v7 library,i can successfully add it in toolbar,but i dont know how to add it in layout.I am attaching image here to clarify what i actually want to do[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can use [PopupMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html).
1st you need to put ImageButton with overflow drawable.
And then in Click listener of that button make PopupMenu and use it.

for more information, see [example](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example)

Comment: i want material style overflow animation and also want that popup menu opens on above overflow icon not below just like it opens in toolbar